# Retrieve Exclusive records from two tables in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables. `Table2` is *referencing* `Table1` with *EmployeeID*. I want to **select records from Table1 whose EmployeeID is not present in Table2**. I have written following SQL query in SQL Server2008 but it does not show required result:

```
SELECT distinct e1.EmployeeID 
FROM   Employee as e1, EmployeeTimeIn as e2
WHERE  e1.EmployeeID <> e2.EID;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Table1 a
        LEFT JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
WHERE   b.EmployeeID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e00a7/1)